# Wondering if I am missing anything with my electrical system set up using Polaris connectors

Tags: electrical, splices

I've received some great advice on here regarding my situation, and now I believe I have a good grasp on how to proceed. I will outline my situation and proposed solution, and would love to see what anyone has to say about it! I apologize to anyone who's read my posts recently, but I'm nothing if not thorough.

I had an electrician set up service from a meter/main with a 200 amp breaker. [image]From the lugs in this meter/main, he then ran 250kcmil Al (2 hot, 1 neutral) and 2awg Al ground 600' to a small cabin workshop with a 100 amp sub panel. 200' into the run, he installed a large pull box at the site of where I am building a garage/small apartment. He also ran conduit from this box to where a 200 amp sub panel will be in the garage.

The plan from here was to use ***Polaris*** connectors to splice each of the feeders and the ground so they both carry on to the cabin and also to the garage. [image]The 250 kcmil will then attach directly to the lugs of the 200 amp garage sub panel.

What does everyone here think of this set up? Even if it isn't your ideal design, does anyone see anything wrong with splicing the feeders in a weatherproof box, after the meter/main, to serve the two separate sub panels? Keep in mind, most of my utilities will run off gas, so no dryers or ranges.

Thanks again for any input and sorry again to anyone who's watching me tread water on this issue in the forum!

Comment: Is your weatherproof box a NEMA 3R on a post aboveground, or a handhole-type box in the ground?

Comment: It's handhole pull box

Comment: "Opinion" makes this explicitly off-topic. If you're looking for pros/cons of one type vs another, or "Are there problems with this plan?" or "Did I miss anything?", that's different

Comment: Sorry, I can see how that was a misleading title. Tried to fix it. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

I think you have shown the [IPLD Series](https://polarisconnectors.com/pdfs/NSi/IPLD_series.pdf), which are dry location only. If below grade (and even recommended if in a NEMA 3R box) you need a [IPLWB](https://polarisconnectors.com/pdfs/NSi/IPLWB.pdf) or other wet location connector.

Comment: Sorry, I put a picture of the first google image I could find. The connectors I will use are rated for wet, below grade locations. Sorry for the confusion. Any problems otherwise with that set up?

Comment: I'm good with it.